# Is it possible to make two scale zones in 9patch image?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to make scalable slider background.

Preview in draw9patch utility looks fine, 
[image: draw9patch]

but on the device middle part is shifted upwards sometimes.
[image: Device screenshot]

Am I doung something wrong? Or there is any kid of workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add black pixels on right and on bottom to define the padding of your view.

Comment: This didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround for this particular case: splitted the image into 2 parts: the border and the middle area.